# Can I create a new global security group with an existing name in Active Directory?

Tags: active-directory, active-directory-group

How can I create a global security group with a name of `finance`, seeing that I already have a user with that name in Active Directory. Is it possible?

Answer (score 2):

You **cannot** have two objects of the same name in the same container - so you cannot create a group called `Finance` in the same container (OU) where the user `Finance` exists. Both user as well as group would be identified by

```
OU=Finance,OU=YourOU,OU=YourOtherOU,dc=YourCompany,dc=com
```

and that won't work - the fully distinguished bane (FQDN) of each object must be unique.

Other than that, there's a requirement that objects must have unique **SAM Account Names** - which by default are the same as the "display" name (`Finance`) - but can be set to something else.

So if your user is called `Finance` and has a SAM account name of `Finance` - then you should be able to create a global group called `Finance` (in a different OU/Container) by settings it's SAM account name to e.g. `FinanceGroup` or something like that.

You're not specifying what language/programming system you're using - if you're trying to create this group in C# / .NET 3.5 or higher, you could use code something like this:

```
using(PrincipalContext ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain))
{
    GroupPrincipal finGroup = new GroupPrincipal(ctx);
    finGroup.DisplayName = "Finance";
    finGroup.SamAccountName = "FinanceGroup";

    finGroup.Save();
}
```